# To find Square root to a precision

Tags: c++, performance

I was just going through the questions various companies ask in interview. I found one was "Find square root of a number to a precision. Function definition should be of something like this: `double getSquareRoot(int num, int precision)`".

I wrote one small function which gives the square root but doesn't care about precision:

```
double getSquareRoot(int num){
 int num1=0, num2=0;
 for(int i=1 ;; i++){
   if(i*i == num){
    std::cout<<i <<" is the sq root"<<std::endl;
    break;
   }
  else if(i*i > num){
   num2 = i;
   num1 = --i;
   break;
  }
} 
 // in the above for loop, i get the num1 and num2 where my input should lie 
 // between them
 // in the 2nd loop below.. now i will do the same process but incrementing 
 // by 0.005 each time
for(double i =num1;i<(double)num2;i+=0.005)
  {
   if(i*i>= num){
     std::cout<<(double)i <<" is the sq root"<<std::endl;
     break;
   }
 }
}
```

Now to reach to precision, i will have to do some tweaks like adding if loops and all. I don't like that. Could you guys help me here? If you are writing code, please explain. I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

This code is very insufficient and this doesn't take care of "till this precision" part of the problem. I only wrote it so that you guy's don't think that i tried a bit.
This

Comment: That is one idiotic question for a c++ interview. For that you need to know an algorithm that does that.

Comment: What does the precision parameter mean? What is `getSquareRoot(10, 4)` supposed to return?

Comment: it should give something like 3.XXXX.Thank you for asking.

Comment: I think the most standard way taught in a lot of programming books for finding square roots is "newtons method", so I would start there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jesse. I am reading Newton method. I am sure this will take a while to code. Read it. Sounds good. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method#Square_root_of_a_number
But after getting each x1 or x2.... i need to ensure that its the square root or not. correct? What would be the complexity here? any Idea? coz complexity is one thing.. otherwise.. 

i can just do something like this

for(int i= num1; i<=num1;i+=0.0000001)

Comment: Wow, brute force. Is it cheating to use `sqrt()`?

Comment: hehe.. Yes + Its no learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off the top of my head, here are two approaches:

- Use [interval bisection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method); you know that the error is no more than the current interval width, so stop iterating once the interval is smaller than required precision. This is very simple, but doesn't converge as quickly as other methods.
- Use an iterative method such as [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) (also known as the [Babylonian method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_method#Babylonian_method) when used to calculate a square root), and estimate the error after each iteration.

To estimate the error, suppose we're trying to find `x0 = sqrt(y)`, so that `x0*x0 = y`. After each iteration, we have a candidate `x = x0 + d`, and we want to estimate the error `d`. If we square `x`, then we get

```
x*x = x0*x0 + 2*x0*d + d*d
    = y + 2*(x-d)*d + d*d
   ~= y + 2*x*d
```

discarding the `d*d` terms, which gets very small as `d` gets small. So we can estimate the error as

```
d ~= (x*x - y) / (2*x)
   = (x - y/x) / 2
```

and stop iterating once this is smaller than the required precision.

If you are using the Babylonian method, then this adds very little work to the iterative calculation, `x = (x + y/x) / 2`, so the result is something like

```
double sqrt(double y, double precision)
{
    double x = y;  // or find a better initial estimate
    for (;;) {
        double z = y/x;
        if (std::abs(x-z) < 2*precision)
            return x;
        x = (x+z)/2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation. Although, i am not able to understand 
x= (x+z)/2. I will go through the Babylonian menthod and if i understand it, well and good, otherwise i will come back with doubt.

Thanks again Mike.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the best answer in this case is: use some big-number library such as [GNU MP Bignum](http://gmplib.org/). It provides [mpf_sqrt](http://gmplib.org/manual/Float-Arithmetic.html#Float-Arithmetic) and similar functions. Default precision for floats can be set via [mpf_set_default_prec](http://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Floats.html).

Best,
-- Christoph

Comment: I want to write my own function from scratch. I appreciate your answer  though. Don't think of it as something you already know. Try making your own algorithm. I wanna go through that process here.

Comment: I know that is tempting to reinvent the wheel, but what you are trying to achieve is probably more complex than at a first glance: you might soon run into floating point issues or similar. Coding for maximum precision is really tedious work. That's why I would always favor libraries from people devoting a lot of work into what seems to be trivia.

Answer (score 2):

Look here for several algorithms: [Methods of computing square roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution ::

```
double root(int num)
{
  double l=0,m=num,h=num,om=0;

       while(m-om)
       {
            om=m;
            m=(l+h)/2.0;
            if(m*m < num)
            {
                l = m;             
            }
            else if(m*m > num)
            {
                h=m;
            }
       }
       return m;
 }
```